# How to pass multi-word string as a radio value?

Tags: php, html

How would I pass "What is Php?" as a value from a radio button.

$records['quiz_name']="What is Php?" or maybe "What is Html?"

```
 echo "<input type=radio name=name_quiz value=".$records['quiz_name'].">".$records['quiz_name']."<br>";
```

I'm having a problem with passing the radio value = "What is Php?" to another page as a value. When I echo $_POST['quiz_name'] on the next page, I get "What" instead of "What is Php?" and when I use var($_POST) i get

```
 var($_POST) = array(1) { ["name_quiz"]=> string(4) "What" }
```

How do I fix this problem? I know it has something to do with the blank spaces. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some quotes in your code which is making it cut the string, just add them

```
echo "<input type=radio name=name_quiz value='".$records["quiz_name"]."'>".$records["quiz_name"]."<br>";
                                           //^                         ^those two
```

Comment: It's always the single and double quotes that get me.